# How can you mirror an autocomplete function in your own aliases (in 14.04)

Tags: bash, 14.04, alias, auto-completion

I have a bunch of aliases that I've used on my 12.04 machine.

example:

```
alias pssh="tsocks ssh"
alias pscp="tsocks scp"
alias prdp="tsocks xfreerdp  ..........SOMETHING ...."
```

These aliases are modifications of regular linux commands (scp,ssh ect.) therefore I'd like these aliases to have the same autocomplete rules as their original counterparts.
I don't want to write my own rules as the rules for the regular commands are perfectly fine.

In 12.04 the following worked perfectly:

```
complete -F _ssh pssh
complete -F _scp pscp
complete -F _ssh prdp
```

This doesn't work in 14.04. If I try to autocomplete I get the following error:

```
bash: completion: function `_ssh' not found
```

If I autocomplete on ssh before I try pssh everything works. As far as I know, it's because the autocomplete rules are not loaded before they are used. Until the autocomplete rules for ssh gets loaded, my rules are invalid and result in an error.

How to I fix this, how do I correctly hook my alias into an autocomplete rule defined for a regular linux command?

Comment: This script worked automagically to me: http://superuser.com/questions/436314/how-can-i-get-bash-to-perform-tab-completion-for-my-aliases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer bash completion releases (>=2.0) improved hugely the time used to load the autocompletion logic. They made them by loading on request the required files, the newer location for these files is:

**/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/**

If you use **ls -lah** to explore such directory you'll find than there exist many soft links. That's because a file is needed for every command/alias, so, if you have pssh, pscp and prdp you'll need to create links with those names:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/psss
sudo ln -s /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/pscp
sudo ln -s /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/prdp
```

Another alternative is to syslink the ssh autocompletion file to /etc/bash_completion.d/

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh /etc/bash_completion.d/ssh
```

The former method will load the _ssh function on every single bash interactive session (making slower the startup).

After using any of the above methods your `complete -F _ssh pssh ...` configuration will relate the _ssh function with your aliases.

Comment: I'd rather have a solution that works in userspace, but this is good enough.